# Remove data from Object if one property is Empty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I got an object like this:

```
data: [
{id: "15012595118", name: ""}, 
{id: "15386434684", name: "Generic"}, 
{id: "15413038239", name: ""}
]
```

I want to remove from the object both id and name if the name is empty.
it should become:

```
data: [
{id: "15386434684", name: "Generic"}
]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use .filter

```
var result = data.filter((d) => d.name != "");
```

Comment: I already tried like this but the resulting object is the same as before

Comment: reassign it to data, `data = [...data].filter((d) => d.name != "");`